# Why does my "Back to Top" button fail on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to do a simple back to top button, and it works on all browsers but Firefox. I don't know what the problem is. Any help?

Script:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 320) {
                $('.scroll-box').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scroll-box').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        $('.scroll-box').click(function () {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 400);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
    .scroll-box {display: none; position: fixed; bottom: 2px; right: 20px; width: 32px; height: 32px;}
    .scroll-box:after {content: 'TOP';}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="scroll-box" title="Back to top"></a>
```

Comment: It works here - Firefox 69.0 (64 bits). Any additional info to make it reproducible here?

Comment: It works on the live site too.. are you on a special version of Firefox? On which OS?

Comment: Your comment just made me test turning uBlock Origin off, and it's actually blocking the script for some reason I cannot fathom. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is being blocked by uBlock Origin. Thanks @Kaddath for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce any problems your code works just fine for me. But I'd like to bring [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) to your attention. It's a native browser method that does exactly what you want without any dependencies:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

You cannot chose the duration of the smooth scroll. But do you really need that anyway?